# UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle not working

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiappearance

In my AppDelegate, I've set the appearance of UITableView like the background and rowHeight etc. But somehow it doesn't work for `separatorStyle`. Is there any reason why it's not working or is this a bug? I have no problems setting `separatorStyle` in the ViewController itself with `tableView.separatorStyle = .None`.

The code in my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarHidden = true

    UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    UITableView.appearance().rowHeight = 40
    UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .None

    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return true
}
```

Strangely, `separatorColor` does work.

EDIT:

When I check `UITableView`, this shows up:

```
// Appearance

var sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount: Int // show special section index list on right when row count reaches this value. default is 0
@availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
var sectionIndexColor: UIColor? // color used for text of the section index
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
var sectionIndexBackgroundColor: UIColor? // the background color of the section index while not being touched
@availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
var sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor: UIColor? // the background color of the section index while it is being touched

var separatorStyle: UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle // default is UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine
var separatorColor: UIColor! // default is the standard separator gray
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
@NSCopying var separatorEffect: UIVisualEffect? // effect to apply to table separators
```

A bit strange, since it's under the comment `Appearance`. The header is not any different compared to `separatorColor` either.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing "strange" or "not working" or "buggy" about this. Not everything is appearance proxy-compatible. Look at the headers:

```
@property (nonatomic) UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle separatorStyle; // default is UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *separatorColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR; // default is the standard separator gray
```

Notice anything? `separatorColor` is marked `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`. `separatorStyle` is not. That means you can use `separatorColor` with the appearance proxy and that you *can't* use `separatorStyle` with the appearance proxy.

Comment: I've checked that as well, but in Swift it doesn't show `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`, or am I looking at the wrong section? (I've edited my question with the one visible in Swift)

Comment: No, it doesn't appear in the Swift translation of the header, but that is not the point. The point is what I said in my answer - _not everything is compatible with the appearance proxy_: and in particular, separator color is, separator style is not. That's the fact. Not a bug. A fact. It doesn't matter whether the header _tells_ you this fact; it remains a fact. I was just using the header to show that this _is_ a fact.

Comment: Chill man, I never said you were wrong or even disagreeing with you. Is it such a crime to question something when both of the methods appears to be the identical? Apparently trying to understand something is worth a down vote. Way to go for the newbies here!

Comment: As I'm using Swift, your method didn't work for figuring out why it doesn't work. So whenever something doesn't work, I'll just have to assume _not everything is compatible_ and move on, giving up and using another way. Great lesson.